# How to bind a field of Model by a Jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model

In my ASP.NET MVC page has a form for new records.

When the user saves a record I need to feed the value of a field of my "Model" within a Jquery function.

```
$('#checkBoxInsertPF').click(function(e){
    @Model.CNPJ = $(".....................").Val('')
});
```

How can I do this within a Jquery Block?

**InsertNewRegister.cshtml**

```
@Model.Cliente model

     @section scripts{
      <script type="text/jscript">
                 $('#checkBoxInsertPF').click(function(e) {
                   @Model.CNPJ = $(".....................").Val('')
     });
     }
```

Comment: Have you tried defining a Razor function in the @functions section of the page? I would try creating one that takes the parameter that you need to set on the model and sets that value to the model. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159877/how-do-i-define-a-method-in-razor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about this the wrong way.  When your model is bound to your view, this is done on the server, before it gets to the client.  As a result, javascript cannot change the values of the model that was sent.  Meaning this:

```
$('#checkBoxInsertPF').click(function(e){
    //Cannot set a model value from client side in this manner
    @Model.CNPJ = $(".....................").Val('')
});
```

Will not work.  However, you can set a hidden input for the model items that you need to update so that when the form is submitted, those values are bound back to the ViewModel in the action method.

**View**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
    ...My Form Elements
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.CNPJ);
}
```

**Script Section**

```
$('#checkBoxInsertPF').click(function(e){
    var newVal = $(".....................").Val('');
    $("#CNPJ").val(newVal);
});
```

This creates an element from your `@Model.CNPJ` field so that you can access it from jQuery and update the values.  On POST, this value will be bound back to the model.