# Calling and binding a C# function to a button in Razor pages, Umbraco

Tags: html, jquery, razor-pages, umbraco7

I want to bind this already existing function to a button.
The function is tested and it completely working. It is important to me to keep all of the code in one razor page.

```
@functions
{
    public void LogCheck()
    {
        string loginemail = Request["loginemail"];
        string loginpassword = Request["loginpassword"];
        string requestedUrl = "/randomtestpage1/";

        IMember memberIfApproved = SC.Code.Controllers.UserController.GetByEmail(loginemail);

        if (Membership.ValidateUser(loginemail, loginpassword))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginemail, true);
            Response.Redirect(requestedUrl);
        }
    }    
}
```

```
<form id="loginForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only form-control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="mx-auto col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" name="loginemail" type="email"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only form-control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="mx-auto col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" name="loginpassword" type="password"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="mx-auto col-sm-10 pb-1 pt-1">
      <button id="loginbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg btn-block" >@Umbraco.AssignedContentItem.GetPropertyValue("signInButtonText")</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I tried adding  `onclick="@LogCheck()"` to the button element, but that messes up the syntax.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Tuple.Create(object, int)' has some invalid arguments

I also tried to call it from a jQuery, but again error.

```
$('#loginbtn').click(function() {
    @LogCheck();
});
```

I tried everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159877/how-do-i-define-a-method-in-razor).

Comment: It is important for me to keep everything from the code in one razor page.

Comment: I would love if somebody also suggests a working solution where the jQuery can be mixed with the Razor blocks.