# Why local function in Razor View doesn't compile?

Tags: c#, razor

I did some reading and found out that you can now have local functions in razor views: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#razor-code-blocks

```
@{
    void RenderName(string name)
    {
        <p>Name: <strong>@name</strong></p>
    }

    RenderName("Mahatma Gandhi");
    RenderName("Martin Luther King, Jr.");
}
```

And that looks great. But, for some reason this doesn't compile on my machine. Why is that? My target framework is .NetCore 3.1 and Visual Studio 2019 16.6.0. There are some error messages:
"Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected" - on the very first line (@using statement) and then:
"Invalid expression term '<'" on the line with HTML.

What is wrong with that?

Comment: You need to define the namespace of your Razor page, so it knows where to look for those functions.

Comment: I do it within one file.

Comment: Then I guess you should be using a `@functions` block.

Answer (score 1):

Functions must be declared inside a `@functions` block in Razor pages.
Here is a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5159940/3548773).

Is this working?

```cs
@functions{
    void RenderName(string name)
    {
        <p>Name: <strong>@name</strong></p>
    }
}
@{
    RenderName("Mahatma Gandhi");
    RenderName("Martin Luther King, Jr.");
}
```

Comment: This is not working either. Function that I'am asking about, is a "local" function. It doesn't need "functions" block. Please, take a look at the link that I have provided in my post.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the solution was really simple. I had a warning that was saying: "Detected Razor downgrade". I just had to remove reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc (2.2) which had been added automatically while creating the project in one of previous versions of VisualStudio.

Comment: By removing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc I lost the ability to use the '@model' tag.